# Python error: 'None Type' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.6

Currently I am making a game using pygame in which, at the moment, I am trying to display fish into the screen to appear randomly around the screen. Later, these fish will add points to score. However I get a type error for when I am trying to load some fish into the game. How can I fix this?

Right now, I am follow a good majority of the code similar to the game 'Squirrel eat Squirrel', which I believe can be played on the Raspberry Pi and have also followed some of sentdex's video on YouTube. I have been debugging it by any means that stop the problem, but I do not understand what this error means or how to fix it.

Right now I run the following code:

```py
global screen, grasspic, bearImg, fishpic, screen_width, screen_height
import random
import pygame
import sys
import math
pygame.init()

camerax = 0
cameray = 0
screen_width = 640
screen_height = 480

fishpic = []
for i in range(1, 3):
    fishpic.append(pygame.image.load('fish%s.png' % i))

for i in range(3):
            allfish.append(makeNewFish(camerax, cameray))
            allfish[i]['x'] = random.randint(0, screen_width)
            allfish[i]['y'] = random.randint(0, screen_height)

def getRandomOffCameraPos(camerax, cameray, objWidth, objHeight):
    cameraRect = pygame.Rect(camerax, cameray, screen_width, screen_height)
    while True:
        x = random.randint(camerax - screen_width, camerax + (2*screen_width))
        y = random.randint(cameray - screen_height, cameray + (2*screen_height))
        objRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, objWidth, objHeight)
        if not objRect.colliderect(cameraRect):
            return x, y

def makeNewFish(camerax, cameray):
    fi = {}
    fi['fishPicture'] = random.randint(0, len(fishpic) - 1)
    fi['width'] = 150
    fi['height'] = 150
    fi['x'], fi['y'] = getRandomOffCameraPos(camerax, cameray, fi['width'], fi['height'])
    fi['rect'] = pygame.Rect((fi['x'], fi['y'], fi['width'], fi['height']))
```

I hoped the output would have fish randomly appear as if the world was 'infinite', but instead I get an error that reads `allfish[i]['x'] = random.randint(0, screen_width)`

> TypeError: 'None Type' object does not support item assignment"

Is there a easy way for this to be fixed?

I'm sorry if I did not explain this good. If it is needed, I can provide more of the code and try to answer anything I did not explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the return statement in the function `makeNewFish`:

```py
def makeNewFish(camerax, cameray):
    fi = {}
    fi['fishPicture'] = random.randint(0, len(fishpic) - 1)
    fi['width'] = 150
    fi['height'] = 150
    fi['x'], fi['y'] = getRandomOffCameraPos(camerax, cameray, fi['width'], fi['height'])
    fi['rect'] = pygame.Rect((fi['x'], fi['y'], fi['width'], fi['height']))

    return fi # <-----
```

With out the return statement, the return value of the function is `None` and `None` is append to `allfish`, when you do:

> ```py
> allfish.append(makeNewFish(camerax, cameray))
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't being using definitions much as I should so this helps a lot.